# (android) Can I use this code in my DiffUtill implementation?

Tags: java, android, android-diffutils

I am now making a `DiffUtil` class to update only changed items in the `RecyclerView`.

I have seen several other sample code.

When comparing two objects, they compared unique values ​​such as id defined in the `Model(Data)` class in `areItemsTheSame()`.

However, I think it is difficult to assign an `id` or `unique value` to the List, or the code is messy.

Do I have to define and compare `id` like this?

Do I really need to define a unique Id variable in the `Model class` that separates each object?
Or shouldn't I use simply the `equals()`?

Using this Is it not just comparing the address of the object, but also the contents of the object?

As an additional question

What is the difference between `DiffUtil.CallBack` and `DiffUtil.ItemCallBack`?

This is my code.

***RoutineModel.java***

```
public class RoutineModel {
    private ArrayList<RoutineDetailModel> routineDetailModels;
    private String routine;

    public RoutineModel(ArrayList<RoutineDetailModel> items, String routine) {
        this.routine = routine;
        this.routineDetailModels = items;
    }

    public ArrayList<RoutineDetailModel> getDetailItemList() {
        return routineDetailModels;
    }

    public int getDetailItemSize() {
        return routineDetailModels.size();
    }

    public String getRoutine() {
        return routine;
    }

    public void setRoutine(String routine) {
        this.routine = routine;
    }
}
```

***RoutineDiffUtil.java***

```
public class RoutineDiffUtil extends DiffUtil.Callback {
    private final List<RoutineModel> oldRoutineList;
    private final List<RoutineModel> newRoutineList;

    public RoutineDiffUtil(ArrayList<RoutineModel> oldRoutineList, ArrayList<RoutineModel> newRoutineList) {
        this.oldRoutineList = oldRoutineList;
        this.newRoutineList = newRoutineList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOldListSize() {
        return oldRoutineList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getNewListSize() {
        return newRoutineList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
        return oldRoutineList.equals(newRoutineList);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
        return oldRoutineList.equals(newRoutineList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got wrong the meaning of `areItemsTheSame()` and `areContentsTheSame()` callbacks. As you see, there are `oldItemPosition` and `newItemPosition` arguments in them. You should use them to compare specific items – not lists themselves.

In `areItemsTheSame()` you have to check whether model at "old" position **in the old list** equals a model at "new" position **in the new list**. This is how DiffUtil knows if it has to make reordering animations.

`areContentsTheSame()` will be called for two items if and only if you return `true` for them in the previous callback. Here you have to check whether visual representation of "old" and "new" models is the same. This is how DiffUtil knows if it has to make "item changing" animations.

To compare two models you have to override `equals()` and `hashCode()`. There you specify conditions under which you consider two models the same. For example, if they have same `routine`. I don't the know context of your task so I can't tell you exactly how to implement them, but usually you just compare all fields. Probably adding an `id` field is a good idea too. Then you can consider models "equal" if they have same `id`. And in `hashCode()` you can just return `Objects.hash(id)`.

Now, speaking about your question about `ItemCallback`. Formally, here is the explanation from docs:

> DiffUtil.Callback serves two roles - list indexing, and item diffing. ItemCallback handles just the second of these, which allows separation of code that indexes into an array or List from the presentation-layer and content specific diffing code.

Practically, `ItemCallback` just has less methods to implement and is used together with [AsyncListDiffer](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/AsyncListDiffer). It's just because missing methods are already implemented under the hood in AsyncListDiffer.

Comment: Thank you for your detail answer. But Can i ask you a few question? 1. In the third paragraph, Does the Previous Callback means areItemsTheSame()? 2. What is the visual representation means? I don't know how to understand the meaning of this word.
3. If I don't use id when overriding the equality comparison of two objects in my code, can I do an equality comparison with a routine string? It is not necessary to compare all the members, right?

Comment: 1. Yes.
2. It means you want to redraw your list item. E.g. you compare items by `id` and it's the same, but you also have a field `routine` and it has been changed. So, items are the same, but contents are not.
3. Yes that's right. But think about the logic of your product. Is `routine` really unique for each model? If no, then you'll have problems: some list items will look the same while being actually different

Comment: However, when comparing the `hashCode` with a routine, even if the routine is not unique and returns true
`areContentsTheSame()` compares the contents (routine, routineDetailModels), so it doesn't matter??

Comment: It will just affect animations then – "changing" animations instead of "creating and removing" animations

Comment: Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the equals and hashcodes of your model classes.

**RoutineModel:**

```
class RoutineModel {
    private ArrayList<RoutineDetailModel> routineDetailModels;
    private String            routine;

    public RoutineModel(ArrayList<RoutineDetailModel> items, String routine) {
        this.routine = routine;
        this.routineDetailModels = items;
    }

    public ArrayList<RoutineDetailModel> getDetailItemList() {
        return routineDetailModels;
    }

    public int getDetailItemSize() {
        return routineDetailModels.size();
    }

    public String getRoutine() {
        return routine;
    }

    public void setRoutine(String routine) {
        this.routine = routine;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        RoutineModel that = (RoutineModel) o;
        return Objects.equals(routineDetailModels, that.routineDetailModels) &&
            Objects.equals(routine, that.routine);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(routineDetailModels, routine);
    }
}
```

**RoutineDiffUtil:**

```
public class RoutineDiffUtil extends DiffUtil.Callback {
    private final List<RoutineModel> oldRoutineList;
    private final List<RoutineModel> newRoutineList;

    public RoutineDiffUtil(ArrayList<RoutineModel> oldRoutineList, ArrayList<RoutineModel> newRoutineList) {
        this.oldRoutineList = oldRoutineList;
        this.newRoutineList = newRoutineList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOldListSize() {
        return oldRoutineList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getNewListSize() {
        return newRoutineList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
        return oldRoutineList.get(oldItemPosition).getRoutine().equals(newRoutineList.get(newItemPosition).getRoutine());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
        return oldRoutineList.get(oldItemPosition).equals(newRoutineList.get(newItemPosition));
    }
}
```

And don't forget to override the equals and hashcode of your **RoutineDetailModel**.

Comment: Thank you. But where does `hashCode()` call in your code?

Comment: and uou mean to override  the equals and hashcode of `RoutineDetailModel` too?

Comment: Hash code is used for elements when adding them to `Hash` constructions to find them easily. It is always recommended to override both of them. And yes you have to override them too for your RoutineDetailModel so the check for areContentsTheSame could return false if some of the params have changed.

Comment: So, Can `RoutineDetail` also override `equals()` and `hashCode()` like Routine?

Comment: Yes, it can, and it should

Comment: Thank you so much :)